# NIFI + Kafka | Serial event processing for events of a partition

Tags: apache-nifi

**Context:** Many of our NiFi flows work like :

1. Consume Events from Kafka using **ConsumeKafka_0_10 processor**
2. Using the data of the event as payload call a REST API using **InvokeHttp processor**
3. Log using **LogAttribute processor**

**Other info:**

1. Let's say the topic from which we are consuming events in step-1 is **topic-1** having 10 partitions
2. Events from within a partition should be processed serially to prevent out-of-order event processing and is generally recommended.

**Question:** Need help/reference on:

1. How to configure my flow so that events of a partition are processed serially (while invoking rest call) or at least events that have the same key are processed serially.

Comment: are you able to separate each partition after ConsumeKafka and use one thread InvokeHttp for each branch?

Comment: @yaprak : no that is precisely we want to do ? Can you please help on this one ?

Answer (score 2):

`ConsumeKafka` adds `kafka.partition` attribute to outputs. so you can leverage that

First of all, try using `PriorityAttributePrioritizer` , this would order them by priority attribute. however all partitions end with `InvokeHttp` (one thread) in this solution which might be bottleneck

[image]

Queue between ConsumeKafka and UpdateAttribute must be `FirstInFirstOut`
.Queue between UpdateAttribute and InvokeHttp must be `PriorityAttributePrioritizer`

UpdateAttribute
[image]

Second way is to use `RouteOnAttibute` to branch partitions after `ConsumeKafka`
note that `InvokeHttp` has to be configured to run one thread only for each branch

[image]

Comment: thanks for answering ... Let me check .. I'will accept the answer then

Answer (score 0):

If you are just concerned with ordering, it will be maintained per partition, as ConsumeKafka_0_10 processor works like any other Kafka consumer, which will process messages sequentially for a partition. Although there is no order guaranty across partitions.

You'll have to keep the concurrency of the InvokeHttp processor as 1, to make sure an ordered delivery.

Comment: "You'll have to keep the concurrency of the InvokeHttp processor as 1," - this is a blocker for us ...